# How to apply styles to all windows in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, styles

I have the following App.xaml file:

```
<Application x:Class="MiniDeviceConfig.App"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
StartupUri="MiniDeviceConfig.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Button.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="CheckBox.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ComboBox.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Common.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="GroupBox.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Label.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="LinkButton.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ListBox.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ListView.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="RadioButton.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Tooltip.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Window.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

In my application, my main window is MiniDeviceConfig.xaml (as seen above).  In my Button.xaml file, I clearly set the button height to some obscene number.  And, this size is reflected in my main window's buttons.  However, some action on the main window triggers a modal window that has more buttons on it.  I was expecting the same tall buttons but no such luck.  How do I get the style to propagate into all windows in the application?

Comment: What sort of modal window is it? One you pop up using MessageBox.Show, or one of your own design?

Comment: Maybe you are setting the button height locally within that modal window.

Comment: Is it also wrong in design view (in Visual Studio)? Can u show us the code where you create and open the modal window. And as John says check so it doesn't have a height set locally or an other Style speced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  There were other resources included that were conflicting.

Answer (score 0):

You can try very helpful class ThemeManager from  http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com. In our project we had similiar problems and solve it by using it.